# 'ApolloProvider' is not exported from 'apollo-client' in React

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

When I run my client, it gives me this error

[image: error message]

This is what's in my App.js,

```
import {ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider} from 'apollo-client'


//--------styles-------
import './App.css';


//Apollo client setup
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
   cache: new InMemoryCache( ),
});


function App() {
  return (

    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
       <div className="App">
          <h1>Hellooooo</h1>
        </div>
    </ApolloProvider>
   
  );
}

export default App;
```

I created another app with graphql, it worked perfectly fine with this v

```
import { ApolloClient, InMemoryCache, ApolloProvider } from '@apollo/client';
```

but when I tried to import like this in my new app, it didnt work either. Please help me figure out what the issue is. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Import from “@apollo/client”?

Comment: As I've mentioned in the post, I already tried it. But it didn't work.

Comment: Whoever is voting down this question, please make sure to leave a comment here. People are going around downvoting just to earn new badges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I deleted node modules folder and reinstalled all the modules. I didn't get the error afterwards. Not sure what the issue was, but this worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (2021), turns out the tried and tested 'turn it off and on again' works here.

Simply cancel out of the live server (assuming you're running react-create-app) and restart it using `npm start` and voila it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

you will have to install @apollo/client and not apollo-client

```
npm install @apollo/client
```

Install this npm module and everything should be fine!

Comment: I got the error with `@apollo/client`. I was going crazy until I deleted node_modules folder and re-installed like the accepted answer suggest.